# What is the difference between BZ and BNZ in instruction pipeline?

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

I am confused between branching instructions BZ and BNZ.
Can anybody, please, explain the concept and working of BZ and BNZ with an example?

Comment: yes, I don't understand branching. Like, how does BZ and BNZ work in instruction pipeline? what does branch taken or not taken mean? And how does instruction flush happen if branch taken or not taken? And what is difference between BZ and BNZ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Your question is very broad since you ask several questions at the same time. Also check the literature you have about CPU instruction sets to see what the "branch if zero" and "branch if not zero" instructions do. If you have a specific (single) question please [edit] your post to describe the problem or misunderstanding you have about the instruction(s).

Comment: They're internally implemented the same way on any given CPU, except for checking the opposite flag conditions.

Answer (score 1):

BZ means **Branch on Zero** , it means the loop will continue if the status/flag register tells the CPU that the previous result (determined by ALU) is zero.

BNZ means **Branch on Not Zero** ( I think u can figure this out :) yeah? ).

It'd be better if someone verifies my answer , I'm not an expert in this field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).